# Cast IEnumerable<Class> to List<string>

Tags: c#, casting, ienumerable

I have a `List<IOhlcv>` and I need to get the `string[]` of `DateTime` strings from the `List`:

```
public interface ITick
{
    DateTimeOffset DateTime { get; }
}

public interface IOhlcv : ITick
{
        decimal Open { get; set; }
        decimal High { get; set; }
        decimal Low { get; set; }
        decimal Close { get; set; }
        decimal Volume { get; set; }
}

//candles is a List<IOhlcv>
var candles = await importer.ImportAsync("FB");
```

What goes here?:

```
string[] x = from p in candles
             orderby p.DateTime ascending
             select What goes here?
```

I can get a `List` of `Datetime` like this also:

```
var sd = candles.Select(i => i.DateTime).ToList();
```

Is there a way to convert the `List<DateTime> to a List<String>` without looping?

I know I can do something like this but I am trying to avoid loops:

```
List<string> dateTimeStringList = new List<string>();

foreach (var d in candles)
    dateTimeStringList.Add(d.DateTime.ToString());

 return dateTimeStringList ;
```

Comment: There is no way to convert one list to another without looping. In order to avoid unnecessary looping you could convert it to `IEnumerable`. Your code then should accept `IEnumerable` instead of `List`. This article might help: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-deferred-execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to convert the `List<DateTime>` to a `List<String>` without
>   looping?

This is how you can do it with [Linq Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>();
list.Add(DateTime.Now);
var format = "yyyy MMMMM dd";
var stringList = list.Select(r => r.ToString(format)).ToList();
```

You can replace `format` above to your favorite [DateTime format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

Comment: `ToList` will essentially do looping

Comment: @tukaef Yes it can do under the hood, but not in my code

Comment: Yeah, sorry, thought OP bothers about the performance, not the code.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
string[] x = from p in candles
         orderby p.DateTime ascending
         select p.DateTime.ToString()
```

You're right, that last one won't. I removed it.